# Compiling a C# program for Windows 7 and above

Tags: c#, .net, .net-framework-version

I wrote a program in C# and I'd like it to work on windows 7 and above, but  my research on the web showed up these two links [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#Overview), [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049(v=vs.110).aspx) which I understand from reading them that there are no common dot net framework installed by default on both windows 7,8,8.1 and 10.

Please pay attention that I could compile for dot net v3.5 and ask windows 8-10 users to install it, but I want my program to run out of the box without asking for installing another dot net framework.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You can compile against .NET Framework 3.5 and set in app.config file which are the supported frameworks (add .NET 4.0 so that it works fine with Windows 8 and above).

Comment: Why don't you just bundle the latest Framework redistributable into your application's installer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 7 comes by default with the framework 3.5.1 as a part of the operating system and newer versions of windows, come with newer frameworks installed on it.

Windows 8 comes with the framework 4.5, this means that it´s also compatible with older versions of the framework.

If your app supports both the .NET Framework 3.5 and 4 or later, Microsoft recommends that you indicate this with multiple entries in the configuration file to avoid .NET Framework initialization errors.

Check these links:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939(v=vs.100).aspx

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/